# SQL - Count Total Number of Orders By Salesperson

Tags: mysql, database, aggregate-functions

I'm a computer science student working on a homework assignment.  I am attempting to total the number of orders for each salesperson.  I want my final output to display the salesperson's name along with the number of orders he/she is given credit for.

The information is stored in two separate tables.

Sample data.

Table 1 - order_t

```
OrderID CustomerID  OrderDate   FulfillmentDate SalespersonID   ShipAdrsID
1   4   2014-09-08  2014-11-25  3   NULL
2   3   2014-10-04  0000-00-00  3   NULL
3   1   2014-07-19  0000-00-00  2   NULL
4   6   2014-11-01  0000-00-00  5   NULL
5   4   2014-07-28  0000-00-00  3   NULL
6   4   2014-08-27  0000-00-00  3   NULL
7   1   2014-09-16  0000-00-00  2   NULL
8   4   2014-09-16  0000-00-00  3   NULL
9   6   2014-09-16  0000-00-00  5   NULL
```

Table 2 - salesperson_t

```
SalespersonID   SalespersonName 
1   "Doug Henny"    
2   "Robert Lewis"  
3   "William Strong"    
4   "Julie Dawson"
```

Here is my latest query.  The problem is it only returns data for a single salesperson that has the ID of 2.  I have no idea why this is happening.

```
SELECT SalespersonName, COUNT(DISTINCT order_t.SalespersonID) AS TotalOrderQuantity
FROM salesperson_t, order_t
WHERE salesperson_t.SalespersonID = order_t.SalespersonID;
```

Comment: You are missing a group by, you are using old-style join-ish syntax no one should use anymore

Comment: You need to get rid of count(distinct).  You want the count of salesperson IDs in the order_t table. That gives you the number of orders. So if there are five '3's in the order table, you want them all summed in your group.  Count distinct is unnecessary for that and probably going to mangle that. Also, I'm surprised your query is working because you haven't grouped on SalesPersonName (i.e. added 'group by SalesPersonName' after the Where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `group by` clause

```
SELECT SalespersonName, COUNT(order_t.SalespersonID) AS TotalOrderQuantity
FROM salesperson_t join order_t on (ordert_t.SalespersonID = salesperson_t.SalespersonID )
group by order_t.SalespersonID
```

Comment: @Brent When an answer has solved your problem, you can show it and give the answerer & yourself reputation by clicking on the accept icon. PS Whereas "thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: @Brent, also, check out Help -> Tour for site etiquette.  Marking questions as solved help others know what DID work, and also solved so others don't need to try and offer more answers when already resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the use of inner join and count(*) with group by

```
SELECT SalespersonName, COUNT(*)  AS NumberOfOrder
FROM salesperson_t 
INNER JOIN order_t on (ordert_t.SalespersonID = salesperson_t.SalespersonID )
GROUP BY order_t.SalespersonID
ORDER BY order_t.SalespersonID
```